# Random noise and DC component

Tags: matlab

I am using the following code to plot a Random noise as follows:

```
n=0:1/250:1;
random_noise=rand(size(n));
N=length(b);
f_bins=0:N-1;
N_2=ceil(N/2);
f_hertz=f_bins*fs/N;
figure
ll=abs(b);
plot(f_hertz(1:N_2),ll(1:N_2))
title('amplitude spectra of random signal')
```

[image: output figure]

The random noise assumes zero mean so why the random noise has a DC component as shown in the above figure? Also a general question, is there is a way to remove the DC component without the use of a filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the [documentation to `rand`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html), you'll see that it generates numbers from a uniform distribution in the range [0,1). The mean for this distribution is 0.5. So simply subtracting 0.5 from your signal will remove the D.C. component:

```
random_noise = rand(size(n)) - 0.5;
```

On the other hand, you probably want to use `randn` instead, which creates a 0-mean normal distribution.

In general, subtracting the mean from a signal removes the D.C. component:

```
signal = signal - mean(signal);
```

BTW: typing `help rand` in MATLAB will also show you the documentation for the function. If you're wondering why `rand` does something your don't expect, reading the documentation should be your first step.